# Amazon AWS Services - Managing/Hosting Java (JAR) Applications

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Is there any kind of services that can host/manage Java (JAR) applications?

If it was a Web Application, then I can use Elastic Beanstalk or OpsWork.

However, my question is that how about Java Applications? For example a simple chat room client/server relationship. Where the server will automatically launch, and will scale accordingly.

It is possible to use AutoScale instances, and then use a new image when I need to redeploy. However, this will stop all the instances. Is there an Amazon service that can support "seamless updating of application" for Java Applications, for example Elastic Beanstalk with rolling updates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take a look at [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/?nc1=h_l2_cn).

Basically, you need to define rules to AutoScale. From Amazon link:

> "Auto Scaling allows you to scale your Amazon EC2 capacity up or down automatically according to conditions you define. With Auto Scaling, you can ensure that the number of Amazon EC2 instances you’re using increases seamlessly during demand spikes to maintain performance, and decreases automatically during demand lulls to minimize costs. Auto Scaling is particularly well suited for applications that experience hourly, daily, or weekly variability in usage. Auto Scaling is enabled by Amazon CloudWatch and available at no additional charge beyond Amazon CloudWatch fees."

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! I'm more interested when you are "updating the application", because Autoscale stops the current instances, dont they?